# Safe way to send parameters to stored procedure in ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sql-injection

I will make simpler than it is to get the answer I need without make you read a lot of code.

MySQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_player
(IN name varchar(100),
 IN isTrue boolean)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;

  insert into tags (name,is_player) values (name,isTrue);

  COMMIT;
END //
```

player_controller.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("call add_player('#{name}', #{is_player})")
```

Two problems I see(if you see more - say):

1. if `name` contains `'` it breaks the call
2. sql injection - I don't use `?` as parameters when I call the stored procedure. The reason is that it's just not working when I'm try with `?`. I tried also change it to `Player.where("add_player(?,?)",name,is_player)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this ?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("call add_player(#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(name)}, #{is_player})")
```

There is another way suggested on the following SO link

[using sanitize_sql_array to escape strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978923/1684207)

The only problem is that `sanitize_sql_array` is not a public method